# Univariate tests of a multivariate model (MANCOVA)

Tags: univariate, mancova

When running multivariate analysis with covariance, the multivariate tests showed all covariates not to be significant, but the grouping variable was significant.

When moving onto univariate tests (between-subject effect), I have noticed that other variables were significant.

My question is, do you only report and move onto variables that were only significant on multivariate tests or do you report all significant variables in univariate, even if they're not significant in the multivariate tests?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you are trying to do? Are you trying to compare outcomes between two groups from some experimental data? What is the structure of the outcome (e.g., continuous, binary, ordinal, count, etc.)? What are some of the  outcomes? Can you write out the model you are trying to fit in equation form?  I'm not clear what you mean by "univariate tests." To me, "univariate" means descriptive statistics. Perhaps you are thinking of bivariate analysis, i.e. the bivariate relationship between the outcome and model covariate. Posting your output will help us help you.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply! I am running an MANCOVA, where I am investigating the grouping variable (UK vs US) on continuous dependent variables of total score (from the questionnaire), reading levels (how much reading each individual does) and their beliefs (investigating myths) whilst controling for age, gender and education. When running MANCOVA, I firstly obtained a non significant Box M, suggesting I have met the assumption of the homogeneity. When looking at my multivariate tests section, the table contains covariate and my grouping variables, with only the group being sig.

Comment: However, when checking the univariate section of my MANCOVA, I noticed that somecovariates are sig with some dependent variables - my question is if i still report those in my publication, or do I only report the univariate (F statistics) section results of those variables that were significant in the multivariate test section?